# C++ Debug executable calls a Release static library

Tags: c++

Suppose now I have a C++ executable `proj`, which is configured to be Debug. This executable will call a static library `libmylib.a`, which is configured to be release. So my question is how the Debug program `proj` will affect the performance of functions in the Release static library `libmylib.a`.

I ask this question as I want to test Release static library `libmylib.a`. However, for unknown reasons, the executable that is used to test the library can only be configured to be Debug. So if the static library passes the test in this situation, can I safely say that everything is fine with the library?

Comment: does your library include header files that contain DEBUG pragmas? And do they affect the size of struct or classes? Header files that the debug application includes will be the main issue and may cause incompatibilities.

Comment: Watch out for scenarios where you give/take ownership of heap pointers between the executable and the library because the debug heap may not be the same as the release heap.

Comment: Two previous comments can be translated into "don't do it, unless you really really need it". I concur.